# How to print a True/False list for Prime numbers with Indexes in Python?

Tags: python, list

My function outputs True for prime numbers and False for non-prime.

```
   def is_prime(x):
      if x < 2:
        return False
      else:
        for n in range(2,x-1):
          if x % n == 0:
            return False
        return True
```

I would like to output the index number for the corresponding True/False statements like this:

```
[0][False]
[1][False]
[2][True]
[3][True]
[4][False]
[5][True]
```

What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you asking how to call a function in a for loop or is there a specific part of your task you're struggling with?

Comment: How exactly is `primelist` defined? You can always use `enumerate` to pair each element of an iterable with an increasing integer.

Comment: @Sayse I edited the question. My struggle is just outputting the indexes for the True/False statements.

Answer (score 3):

```
def is_prime(x):
  if x < 2:
    return False
  else:
    for n in range(2,x-1):
      if x % n == 0:
        return False
    return True   
    

def num_range(x):
    for i in range(x):
        print([i],[is_prime(i)])

num_range(5) # send how many numbers you want to print
```

This gives output

```
[0] [False]                                                                                                                                   
[1] [False]                                                                                                                                   
[2] [True]                                                                                                                                    
[3] [True]                                                                                                                                    
[4] [False]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, you're essentially returning the flags in the sieve of Eratosthenes.  Perhaps you should use that method directly:

```
def sieve(x):
    result = [False]*2+[True]*(x-1)
    p,i = 2,1                                            # 2,3,5,7,...
    while p*p<=x:                                        # only up to √x
        if result[p]:                                    # found a prime
            result[p*p::p] = [False]*len(result[p*p::p]) # flag multiples
        p,i = p+i,2                                      # next candidate                            
    return result
```

output:

```
x = 10
for i,isPrime in enumerate(sieve(x)):
    print([i],[isPrime])

[0] [False]
[1] [False]
[2] [True]
[3] [True]
[4] [False]
[5] [True]
[6] [False]
[7] [True]
[8] [False]
[9] [False]
[10] [False]
```